# Merging elements in XSLT transformation

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

i have below input xml and want to convert into single element please go through input and expected output and provide any solution. its required using XSLT 1.0

input xml is as below

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
    <PrintableDocument>
        <SubjectData>
            <SubjectIND AECBBureauHitResponseStatus="Hit" AECBConsentFlag="0" AECBInquiryFlag="0"
                Age="26" CHMCallDone="" CHMConsentFlag="0" CHMInquiryFlag="0" DOB="1993-08-04"
                EmiratesID="784-1993-5878784-1" FullName="ROSS GIULI" Gender="F" Name="ROSS"
                Nationality="UAE" PdtDone="0" Role="M" Surname="GIULI">
                <ExternalSources>
                    <UAEbureau AECBBureauHitResponseStatus="Hit" AECBConsentFlag="0"
                        AECBInquiryFlag="0" Age="26" CHMCallDone="" CHMConsentFlag="0"
                        CHMInquiryFlag="0" DOB="1993-08-04" EmiratesID="784-1993-5878784-1"
                        FullName="ROSS GIULI" Gender="F" Name="ROSS" Nationality="UAE" PdtDone="0"
                        Role="M" Surname="GIULI">
                        <Contracts>
                            <Contract TotalAmount="12000" >
                                <History Year="2018">
                                    <Period ReferenceDate="012018" Balance="444"
                                        OverdueAmount="200" DaysPaymentDelay="8" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                    <Period ReferenceDate="012018" Balance="885000"
                                        OverdueAmount="100" DaysPaymentDelay="1" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                    <Period ReferenceDate="022018" Balance="885000"
                                        OverdueAmount="100" DaysPaymentDelay="1" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                </History>
                                <History Year="2017">
                                    <Period ReferenceDate="022017" Balance="25000"
                                        OverdueAmount="50" DaysPaymentDelay="0" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                    <Period ReferenceDate="022017" Balance="777" OverdueAmount="50"
                                        DaysPaymentDelay="1" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                </History>
                            </Contract>
                            <Contract TotalAmount="12000" >
                                <History Year="2018">
                                    <Period ReferenceDate="012017" Balance="222"
                                        OverdueAmount="200" DaysPaymentDelay="8" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                    <Period ReferenceDate="012017" Balance="123"
                                        OverdueAmount="100" DaysPaymentDelay="1" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                    <Period ReferenceDate="022017" Balance="8987"
                                        OverdueAmount="100" DaysPaymentDelay="1" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                </History>
                                <History Year="2017">
                                    <Period ReferenceDate="022018" Balance="121"
                                        OverdueAmount="50" DaysPaymentDelay="0" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                    <Period ReferenceDate="022018" Balance="2311" OverdueAmount="50"
                                        DaysPaymentDelay="1" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                </History>
                            </Contract>
                        </Contracts>
                    </UAEbureau>
                </ExternalSources>
            </SubjectIND>
        </SubjectData>
    </PrintableDocument>
</Data>
`
```

expected output will be as below

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
    <PrintableDocument>
        <SubjectData>
            <SubjectIND AECBBureauHitResponseStatus="Hit" AECBConsentFlag="0" AECBInquiryFlag="0"
                Age="26" CHMCallDone="" CHMConsentFlag="0" CHMInquiryFlag="0" DOB="1993-08-04"
                EmiratesID="784-1993-5878784-1" FullName="ROSS GIULI" Gender="F" Name="ROSS"
                Nationality="UAE" PdtDone="0" Role="M" Surname="GIULI">
                <ExternalSources>
                    <UAEbureau AECBBureauHitResponseStatus="Hit" AECBConsentFlag="0"
                        AECBInquiryFlag="0" Age="26" CHMCallDone="" CHMConsentFlag="0"
                        CHMInquiryFlag="0" DOB="1993-08-04" EmiratesID="784-1993-5878784-1"
                        FullName="ROSS GIULI" Gender="F" Name="ROSS" Nationality="UAE" PdtDone="0"
                        Role="M" Surname="GIULI">
                        <Contracts>
                            <Contract TotalAmount="12000" >
                                <History Year="2018">
                                    <Period ReferenceDate="012018" Balance="444"
                                        OverdueAmount="200" DaysPaymentDelay="8" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                    <Period ReferenceDate="012018" Balance="885000"
                                        OverdueAmount="100" DaysPaymentDelay="1" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                    <Period ReferenceDate="022018" Balance="885000"
                                        OverdueAmount="100" DaysPaymentDelay="1" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                </History>
                                <History Year="2017">
                                    <Period ReferenceDate="022018" Balance="25000"
                                        OverdueAmount="50" DaysPaymentDelay="0" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                    <Period ReferenceDate="022018" Balance="777" OverdueAmount="50"
                                        DaysPaymentDelay="1" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                </History>
                            </Contract>
                            <Contract TotalAmount="12000" >
                                <History Year="2018">
                                    <Period ReferenceDate="012018" Balance="222"
                                        OverdueAmount="200" DaysPaymentDelay="8" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                    <Period ReferenceDate="012018" Balance="123"
                                        OverdueAmount="100" DaysPaymentDelay="1" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                    <Period ReferenceDate="022018" Balance="8987"
                                        OverdueAmount="100" DaysPaymentDelay="1" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                </History>
                                <History Year="2017">
                                    <Period ReferenceDate="022018" Balance="121"
                                        OverdueAmount="50" DaysPaymentDelay="0" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                    <Period ReferenceDate="022018" Balance="2311" OverdueAmount="50"
                                        DaysPaymentDelay="1" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                </History>
                            </Contract>
                        </Contracts>
                        <ConsolidatedHistory>
                                <History Year="2018">
                                    <Period ReferenceDate="012018" Balance="444"
                                        OverdueAmount="200" DaysPaymentDelay="8" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                    <Period ReferenceDate="012018" Balance="885000"
                                        OverdueAmount="100" DaysPaymentDelay="1" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                    <Period ReferenceDate="022018" Balance="885000"
                                        OverdueAmount="100" DaysPaymentDelay="1" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                        <Period ReferenceDate="012018" Balance="222"
                                        OverdueAmount="200" DaysPaymentDelay="8" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                    <Period ReferenceDate="012018" Balance="123"
                                        OverdueAmount="100" DaysPaymentDelay="1" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                    <Period ReferenceDate="022018" Balance="8987"
                                        OverdueAmount="100" DaysPaymentDelay="1" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                </History>
                                <History Year="2017">
                                    <Period ReferenceDate="022017" Balance="25000"
                                        OverdueAmount="50" DaysPaymentDelay="0" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                    <Period ReferenceDate="022017" Balance="777" OverdueAmount="50"
                                        DaysPaymentDelay="1" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                         <Period ReferenceDate="022017" Balance="121"
                                        OverdueAmount="50" DaysPaymentDelay="0" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                    <Period ReferenceDate="022017" Balance="2311" OverdueAmount="50"
                                        DaysPaymentDelay="1" ContractStatus="U"></Period>
                                </History>
                        </ConsolidatedHistory>
                    </UAEbureau>
                </ExternalSources>
            </SubjectIND>
        </SubjectData>
    </PrintableDocument>
</Data>
`
```

sample xslt code is

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="Data">
        <xsl:element name="Data">
            <xsl:call-template name="SubjectData" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="SubjectData">
        <xsl:element name="SubjectData">
            <xsl:for-each select="SubjectData/SubjectIND">
                <xsl:element name="SubjectIND">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="*[name()!='ExternalSources']" />
                    <xsl:element name="ExternalSources">
                        <xsl:element name="UAEbureau">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="ExternalSources/UAEbureau/@*"/>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="*[name()!='Contracts']" />
                            <xsl:element name="Contracts">
                                <xsl:for-each select="ExternalSources/UAEbureau/Contracts/Contract">
                                    <xsl:element name="Contract">
                                        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                                        <xsl:copy-of select="CommonInfo"/>
                                        <xsl:for-each select="History">
                                            <xsl:sort select="@Year" order="descending"/>
                                            <xsl:variable name="key" select="@Year"/>
                                            <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::History[@Year=$key])">
                                                <xsl:element name="History">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="Year"><xsl:value-of select="@Year"/></xsl:attribute>
                                                    <xsl:for-each select="../History[@Year=$key]">
                                                        <xsl:element name="Period">
                                                            <xsl:attribute name="ReferenceDate"><xsl:value-of select="@ReferenceDate"/></xsl:attribute>
                                                            <xsl:attribute name="Balance"><xsl:value-of select="@Balance"/></xsl:attribute>
                                                            <xsl:attribute name="OverdueAmount"><xsl:value-of select="@OverdueAmount"/></xsl:attribute>
                                                            <xsl:attribute name="DaysPaymentDelay"><xsl:value-of select="@DaysPaymentDelay"/></xsl:attribute>
                                                            <xsl:attribute name="ContractStatus"><xsl:value-of select="@ContractStatus"/></xsl:attribute>
                                                        </xsl:element>
                                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                                </xsl:element>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>`
```

here Contract will be 1 to many and History under contract also vary depending on years.
Please suggest any approach to following situation.

Comment: Amit, StackOverflow is a service designed to answer your questions, not to write your code for you. You haven't asked us a question, you have asked us to do your work for you.You need to start again: tell us where you got stuck and what information you need to get over that hurdle. Sorry, but I'm going to vote to close this.

Comment: Hi @MichaelKay I am sorry for my mistake.
I am not able to group Contract[0-N] /History to ConsolidatedHistory/History year wise.
I have tried the below logic but not working.

<xsl:for-each select="ExternalSources/UAEbureau/Contracts/Contract">
                                    <xsl:element name="Contract">
                                        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                                        <xsl:copy-of select="CommonInfo"/>

Comment: <xsl:for-each select="History">
                                            <xsl:sort select="@Year" order="descending"/>
                                            <xsl:variable name="key" select="@Year"/>
                                            <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::History[@Year=$key])">
                                                <xsl:element name="History">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="Year"><xsl:value-of select="@Year"/></xsl:attribute>

Comment: <xsl:for-each select="../History[@Year=$key]">
                                                        <xsl:element name="Period">
                                                            <xsl:attribute name="ReferenceDate"><xsl:value-of select="@ReferenceDate"/></xsl:attribute>
                                                            <xsl:attribute name="Balance"><xsl:value-of select="@Balance"/></xsl:attribute>
                                                            <xsl:attribute name="OverdueAmount"><xsl:value-of select="@OverdueAmount"/></xsl:attribute>

Comment: <xsl:attribute name="DaysPaymentDelay"><xsl:value-of select="@DaysPaymentDelay"/></xsl:attribute>
                                                            <xsl:attribute name="ContractStatus"><xsl:value-of select="@ContractStatus"/></xsl:attribute>
                                                        </xsl:element>
                                                    </xsl:for-each>

Comment: </xsl:element>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                        </xsl:for-each>

Comment: @AmitShah - Can you please edit your question to include the XSLT, as code is hard to read in comments. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @MichaelKay I have posted sample xslt code what I have tried so far please suggest.

Comment: This is a grouping question. In XSLT 1.0, the preferred method is Muenchian grouping. Start here and post specific questions if you cannot make it work:  http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html -- Note also that most of your existing code is redundant and could be replaced by the *identity transform* template.